# Kivy-If A button bind with callback(instance), how to call other functions

Tags: python, kivy

What i want is that:

Press button A >> Open choose folder dialog >> Select folder A >> Show path A in label A;

Press button B >> Open choose folder dialog >> Select folder B >> Show path B in label B.

If you run my code, it works very good. But if you read the code carefully, you will find a issue.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0
<Root>:
    loadFolderA: loadFolderA
    loadFolderB: loadFolderB

    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    Button:
        id: selectFolderA
        text: 'select folder A'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.21, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: root.show_select_folder_dialogA()

    Button:
        id: selectFolderB
        text: 'select folder B'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.785, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: root.show_select_folder_dialogB()

    Label:
        id: loadFolderA
        text: 'path A'
        font_size: 30
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.21, 'center_y': .5}

    Label:
        id: loadFolderB
        text: 'path B'
        font_size: 30
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.785, 'center_y': .5}

<SelectFolder>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Choose"
                on_release: root.choose(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
''')

class Root(GridLayout):
    posixPathA = StringProperty('')
    posixPathB = StringProperty('')

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_select_folder_dialogA(self):
        content = SelectFolder(choose=self.chooseA, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Select Folder", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def show_select_folder_dialogB(self):
        content = SelectFolder(choose=self.chooseB, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Select Folder", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def chooseA(self, path, filename):
        self.posixPathA = path
        self.loadFolderA.text = self.posixPathA
        self.dismiss_popup()

    def chooseB(self, path, filename):
        self.posixPathB = path
        self.loadFolderB.text = self.posixPathB
        self.dismiss_popup()

class SelectFolder(FloatLayout):
    choose = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

The function 'show_select_folder_dialog' I write in two times, one for binding with button A, one for button B. And same to the function 'choose'. It really makes me unhappy. So I want to know if I can make the Code know which button is pressed, then pass the folder path to the right label. Hope someone can help.

#

#

It takes all night, now i come to this place:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0
<Root>:
    loadFolderA: loadFolderA
    loadFolderB: loadFolderB

    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    NewButton:
        id: selectFolderA
        text: 'select folder A'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.21, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: self.callback()

    NewButton:
        id: selectFolderB
        text: 'select folder B'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.785, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: self.callback()

    Label:
        id: loadFolderA
        text: 'path A'
        font_size: 30
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.21, 'center_y': .5}

    Label:
        id: loadFolderB
        text: 'path B'
        font_size: 30
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.785, 'center_y': .5}

<SelectFolder>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Choose"
                on_release: root.choose(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
''')

class NewButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Button, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def callback(instance):
        print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)
        Root.show_select_folder_dialog(Root)

class Root(GridLayout):
    posixPathA = StringProperty('')
    posixPathB = StringProperty('')

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_select_folder_dialog(self):
        content = SelectFolder(choose=self.choose, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Select Folder", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def choose(self, path, filename):
            self.posixPathA = path
            self.loadFolderA.text = self.posixPathA
            self.dismiss_popup()


class SelectFolder(FloatLayout):
    choose = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

My plan is that use Callback(instance) to know which button was calling the function. Then call the Function to open choose folder dialog. It's strange but this line works here:

```
Root.show_select_folder_dialog(Root)
```

But I cannot go further. Now the function report error:'TypeError: choose() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename''

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: hi @Carcigenicate , what about now? My question is detect which button is pressed then send output to the right place. I did my best. Sorry for my English:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove both the duplicate A/B methods by sending an idx with the button press:

```py
Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0
<Root>:
    loadFolderA: loadFolderA
    loadFolderB: loadFolderB

    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    Button:
        id: selectFolderA
        text: 'select folder A'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.21, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: root.show_select_folder_dialog("A")  # send an idx here

    Button:
        id: selectFolderB
        text: 'select folder B'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.785, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: root.show_select_folder_dialog("B")  # send an idx here

    Label:
        id: loadFolderA
        text: 'path A'
        font_size: 30
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.21, 'center_y': .5}

    Label:
        id: loadFolderB
        text: 'path B'
        font_size: 30
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.785, 'center_y': .5}

<SelectFolder>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Choose"
                on_release: root.choose(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
''')

from functools import partial

class Root(GridLayout):
    posixPathA = StringProperty('')
    posixPathB = StringProperty('')

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_select_folder_dialog(self, idx):
        # pass the idx to the choose method
        content = SelectFolder(choose=partial(self.choose, idx),
                               cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Select Folder", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def choose(self, idx, path, filename):
        if idx == "A":  # The "A" button was selected
            self.posixPathA = path
            self.loadFolderA.text = self.posixPathA
        else:  # You can use more elifs if you like
            self.posixPathB = path
            self.loadFolderB.text = self.posixPathB
        self.dismiss_popup()

class SelectFolder(FloatLayout):
    choose = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

Comment: Hi, @noEmbryo , Amazing job, works perfect on my machine. New knowledge to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Friend i have got a simple solution for your code which makes it easier to recognise which button  you have chosen for that you can use easygui module:

```
choice = easygui.buttonbox(title="Choose button",msg="Choose a button",choices=["Button 1","Button 2",])
```

which opens a box like:

[image]

And now you can use your if condition to and do the rest of the process.